# How to update appsettings.json value using Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I want to get a build number and display it on my website logo. So whenever there is a new build, I want a new build number and pass it to the AppSettings.json file so then I can fetch the build number from there and use it.

```html
"AppSettings": {
    "EmailPopPort": "111",
    "PopEmail": "confirm@gmail.com",
    "PopPassword": "sBzce",
    "AvailableStacks": [
      "AAA",
      "Plan",
      "US"
    ],
    "SmsProvider": "SmsGlobal",
    "Version":  "Dev"
    }
```

I want to update the above "Version" In appsettings.json through the pipeline in Azure. What would be the best technique to do that?

Comment: Building in Visual Studio? Building in an Azure DevOps pipeline? Building in something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-app-settings

the values of configuration in App Service override the ones in Web.config or appsettings.json.

So, just need to change to configuration settings is ok.

How to do it in Azure pipeline:

**1, Create a service connection:**

[image]

[image]

**2, Give the related service principal required permission:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Note: The role assign need 5 minutes to apply, please wait.)

**3, Use DevOps pipeline to change the app settings:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you use YAML, it is

```
steps:
- task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
  displayName: 'xxx'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xxx
    appName: xxx
    resourceGroupName: 'xxx'
    appSettings: |
     [
        {
         "name": "bowmantest",
         "value": "bowmantestvalue",
         "slotSetting": false
        }
     ]
```

4, After that, just wait, it will be successful:

[image]

Comment: And using Console in Azure or "Kudu" ? any references about it?

Comment: @Bowman Zhu-MSFT What if I want to use output of arm template deployment and provide the value to appsetting json? No app services involved, so take the example of deploying arm template with app insight instance and output instrumentation key from AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 to a variable and use it to update the value in an already existing app setting json key? The app is not deployed in azure.